# Show that equality holds in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality |⟨x, y⟩| ≤ ∥x∥ ∥y∥ . for x, y if and only if x and y are linearly dependent...

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Could someone please help me with this proof?

I have written up this but I not sure if it is a *full* proof, since it is an if and only if statement. Could someone read and inform me where I can go from here if there is more to prove?

So, if **y**=0 then the result is trivial.
Hence, assume y is non-zero.

Let z = x - $x_y$ = x - $\frac{<x,y>}{<y,y>}y$ , *y*

= < x, y > - $\frac{< x,y >}{< y,y >}$ < y,y >

= 0

Thus, z (the projection of x) is a vector orthogonal to y and hence, if x and y are linearly dependent then the equality holds.

I am unsure whether this satisfies ==> direction of the proof or <== or both (i'm assuming it proves ==>, though).

I tried to further my proof by saying:

for (<==) let y=ax (ie. x and y are linearly independent) for some real a.

so, |< x,y >| = |< x,ax >| = ||x||.||ax||

now, |a| |< x,x >| = ||x||.||ax|| ≥ 0

if < x,x > = 0 then the inequality clearly holds.

but now I am unsure of how to expand on if < x,x > doesn't equal 0.

Comment: What dimension vector space are you working over? If it's not $2$, then your definition of (the negation of) linear independence is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Following your idea:

$1).\ x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent, the there is an $a\in \mathbb C$ such that $x=ay$. A direct substitution shows that equality holds in Cauchy Schwartz.

$2).$ If $x$ and $y$ are not dependent, then there must be a vector $z\perp y$ and a non-zero scalar $a$ such that $x=ay+z, $ in which case  $\|x\|^2\cdot \|y\|^2=(a^2\|y\|^2+\|z\|^2)\cdot \|y\|^2=a^2\|y\|^4+\|z\|^2\cdot \|y\|^2$ whereas $|\langle x,y\rangle|^2=a^2\|y\|^4$, so strict inequality holds.

Comment: if Z and Y are orthogonal would $||z||^2 . ||y||^2$ not equal 0/cancel out?

Comment: since $z\perp y$ the Pyth Theorem applies: $||z||^2 + ||y||^2=(||z|| +||y||)^2$